# Making JQuery-UI Plugin work with Errai

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, gwt, errai

I'm trying to make the *[XEditable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)* Jquery-ui plugin work with GWT/Errai. 
However, when clicking the supposedly "*x-editable*" field nothing happens. What could be wrong in my code:

This is my code:

**Java:**

```
@Dependent
@Page
@Templated
public class XeditableTest extends Composite {

    @DataField
    private Element xfield;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        xeditable(xfield);
    }

public static native void xeditable(Element el) /*-{
    $wnd.alert($wnd.$(el).length);
    $wnd.$(function(){      
            $wnd.$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
            $wnd.$(el).editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                   if($wnd.$.trim(value) == '') return 'This field is required';
                }
            });
        }
    )
}-*/;

    @EventHandler("xfield")
    public void onAnchorClicked(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        clickEvent.preventDefault();
    }   

}
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <a href="#" data-field="xfield" id="firstname" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-placeholder="Required" data-original-title="Enter your firstname" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
</div>
```

Update:

Error I get after passing Element to the `xeditable` method:

```
ERROR] Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
[ERROR]     at com.myapp.client.local.XeditableTest.xeditable(XeditableTest.java)
[ERROR]     at com.myapp.client.local.XeditableTest.setup(XeditableTest.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't attach the element with id `firstname` to the DOM before you call your xeditable method, jquery won't find it.  you can check by putting alert($('#firstname').length); in your xeditable JSNI code.

i find it is easier/more predictable to pass the element into jquery.  so, bind your ui (ie, have a `@DataField Element firstname;` and then pass firstname as an argument into `xeditable` and use $(firstname).editable(...)

note however, that some jquery plugins don't work on elements that are not yet attached to the DOM.  you can be safe by ensuring the widget is attached before calling jquery: [For what is the AttachEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131920/for-what-is-the-attachevent)

---

edit:  your updated code looks wrong.  also, you don't need $wnd in front of alert, only to access globals (like jquery) that are defined in the main doc frame.

here is an example where i do this with the datatables.js jquery plugin:

```
private native JavaScriptObject _init(TableElement element) /*-{
    var c = $wnd.jQuery(element);
    var dataTable = c.dataTable({
        "bAutoWidth" : false
    });
    return dataTable;
}-*/;
```

Comment: also - this is not the problem with your code, but are you sure that xfield is initialized?  you may need to have `private Element xfield = DOM.createDiv();`  (replace Div with whatever element you are using).  you cannot use @Inject with Elements since they don't have constructors.

Comment: I have now: @DataField private Element xfield = DOM.createElement("a");

Comment: I have fixed this issue already. Anyway, your answer was the closest one in the fix I have. So I will accept it as the correct one.